# How do I ensure my useEffect with no dependencies is only called once in Ionic/React?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-hooks, rendering

I'm building an Ionic 7, React 18 application and having some trouble understanding a basic useEffect principle.  I have this App.tsx file

```
setupIonicReact();

const App: React.FC = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Loading user profile info in app..." + new Date().getUTCMilliseconds());
    UserService.getProfile()
      .then((user) => {
        console.log("User: " + JSON.stringify(user));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching profile:", error);
      });
  }, []);
  

  return (
    <IonApp>
      <IonReactRouter>
        <IonHeader>
          <IonToolbar>
            <IonButtons slot="start">
              <IonButton>
                <IonIcon icon={logoReact} />
              </IonButton>
            </IonButtons>
            <IonTitle>LOL Greetings</IonTitle>
            <IonButtons slot="end">
              <IonButton>
                <IonIcon icon={search} />
              </IonButton>
              <IonButton>
                <IonIcon icon={personCircle} />
              </IonButton>
            </IonButtons>
          </IonToolbar>
          <IonToolbar>
            <CategorySelectComponent />
          </IonToolbar>
        </IonHeader>

        <IonContent className="ion-padding" scroll-y>
        Test
        </IonContent>
      </IonReactRouter>
    </IonApp>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This is called from my mainn.tsx file

```
const container = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(container!);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

THe problem is I'm noticing the "useEffect" is getting called twice (I can see two calls to my UserProfile.getProfile" call.  How do I ensure that it is only called once?  I thought that passing an empty dependency array ensures the useEffect only executes once, but I guess I'm wrong about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry, since you have used `<StrictMode>`, your components will re-run Effects an extra time to find bugs caused by missing Effect cleanup. In your **production** build, your effects will be run only **once**.

See https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode.

Answer (score 0):

It is because strict mode. It will not be triggered twice on production build, but triggers twice on development mode. It is not any danger but provides some benefits to catch some errors. To sum up, dont care :)